Why does lftp does not work with special characters in password?
Why lftp -u testuser,":abcd[S\ymefgH" -e "cd;bye" server1 does not work but when using ftp server1 manually it works
I tried single quotes as well but it just stucks on cd `~' [Delaying before reconnect: 28]
It is a problem only with some passwords with special characters not all of them.I am not sure which character is causing this, i believe it could be : causing the problem.

One possible way to deal with complex passwords and ftp clients is to create/edit .netrc file in your home directory and add record like:
host server1
login testuser
password :abcd[S\ymefgH

This will work with most of the ftp clients. And your command will become something like:
lftp -e "cd;bye" server1

BTW you can accomplish this with standard ftp client.
